# How to fix wordpress japanese link won't work issue

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue about links in wordpress. It can't link an image even though it already had same name in japanese when i call it. It says Page not found.

Comment: Can you provide some code that is not working?

Comment: Please share some code of where you're trying to link the image.